# Angular - How to reuse data in manually nested components

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have two Angular components, `checklist-page` and `checklist`.
`checklist-page` downloads the data from the backend

I would like to use the `checklist` component multiple times inside the `checklist-page` component.

I'd like to use the downloaded data of `checklist-page` in `checklist` components.

**The twist** is, I can't choose the basic parent-child component nesting way, because I would like to customly parameterize each `checklist` instances this way:

```
<checklist-page [type]='locations'>
   <checklist [checklistData]="parentComponentData" [filter]='visited'>
   <checklist [checklistData]="parentComponentData" [filter]='remaining'>
   <checklist [checklistData]="parentComponentData" [filter]='visited' [userId]=123>
   <checklist [checklistData]="parentComponentData" [filter]='visited' [userId]=234>
   <checklist [checklistData]="parentComponentData" [filter]='remaining' [userId]=456>
   <checklist [checklistData]="parentComponentData" [filter]='remaining' [userId]=456>
   .
   .
   .
</checklist-page>
```

So, in short, I don't know exactly what is the content of the `checklist-page` template, it can be vary.

How can I pass the data from `checklist-page` to `checklist` in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of approaches from this link.I prefer the service one
https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not that I'm looking for

Comment: okay, please extend info, coz from the descr I don't see why it does not work

Comment: I think you didn't get the twist part of my description :) Everything is there. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

You can use dynamic components loader https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader.